# wildcard capturing java method argument and parameter type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm reading the book `Java generics and collections` by  Maurice Naftalin.

In the section on wildcard capturing, the author gave an example

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list) { 
    rev(list); 
}

private static <T> void rev(List<T> list) {
    List<T> tmp = new ArrayList<T>(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, tmp.get(list.size()-i-1));
    }
}
```

But I thought type `List<T>` is a subtype of `List<?>` (where `List<?>` is a shorthand syntax for `List<? extends Object>`) (is my assumption of `List<T>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Object>` even correct?), so inside the `reverse` method, how can we pass variable `list` (of type `List<? extends Object>`) to `rev` method, where the `rev` method's parameter is of type `List<T>`?

Comment: Why not? As long as the compiler can infer the type in advance...

Comment: doesn't it violate the "substitution principle"? where "substitution principle" is defined as --- Substitution Principle: a variable of a given type may be assigned a value of any subtype
of that type, and a method with a parameter of a given type may be invoked with an
argument of any subtype of that type.

Comment: Why would it? `T` is not specified to be a specific type, and neither is `?`, so there *is* no subtyping being performed.

Answer (score 3):

> how can we pass variable list (of type `List<? extends Object>`) to rev method

You're not.

Every list has a type: you can't create a `new ArrayList<?>` or a `new ArrayList<? extends String>`. You can create a `new ArrayList<String>`, and assign it to a variable with a wildcard type.

So, you can invoke a method taking `List<T>`, even with a `List<?>` as the parameter, provided the compiler can infer that there is *some* type which is consistent with the bounds. You don't know the type, but the compiler can.

Answer (score 2):

> But I thought type `List<T>` is a subtype of `List<?>`

This is not really true: remember that generics in Java are *invariant*. This means that even if X is a subtype of Y, `List<X>` will NOT be a subtype of `List<Y>`.

The reason the code example works is that the `reverse` method matches any `List` type, even a raw type.

Answer (score 2):

In this declaration :

```
private static <T> void rev(List<T> list) {...}
```

`T` is a method parameterized type that without explicit bound refers to any type.

You can so passed in the method a variable declared as `List<? extends Object>`, `List<?>` or even `List<String>` as it accepts any type in the `List`.